# Security of SWIFFT Hash Function

Tags: provable-security, post-quantum-cryptography

Is the SWIFFT hash function described in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIFFT

still considered a provably secure one way function?  Is it also considered secure against attacks by a quantum computer?  Would it be a good candidate for a post-quantum (quantum safe) hash?

Comment: Note: There is currently no reason to believe that standard hash functions such as SHA2/SHA3 are broken by quantum computers beyond the speedup provided by Grover's algorithm, hence those are "good candidates for a post-quantum hash".

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a bit careful here, I think.

The SWIFFT hash function is linear and does not behave like a random oracle. It is second pre-image resistant in an asymptotic sense. The fact that this property seems to depend on "a relatively mild assumption about the worst-case difficulty of finding short vectors in cyclic/ideal lattices" would seem to suggest (subject to verification) it might be post quantum secure (like NTRU which is also based on cyclic/ideal lattices).

However, the SWIFFT function is defined for **fixed input length**. Hence it cannot be directly used as a one way hash function for arbitrary length inputs, maybe it could be a building block for a post quantum secure one way hash function, I am not sure.

Comment: I wouldn't place a tremendous amount of trust in the post-quantum security of ideal lattice assumptions. The area is basically brand new and some quantum attacks have already been demonstrated on special cases. The fixed input length thing, meh. A literature search would probably turn up a provably-secure domain extension transform to allow you to get to arbitrary-length inputs.